# STM32 UART single-wire half-duplex communication

Tags: stm32, uart, 1-wire

I tried to make single-wire half-duplex communication with a UART using the STM32F103C8 controller. In single-wire half-duplex communication, a TX pin is used for transmitting and receiving the data.

I had configured the pins and register with the help of a datasheet (reference manual for STM32F103C8). So I tried to transmit the data from one bluepill board (STM32F103C8) and to receive the data in another bluepill board (STM32F103C8). But I am not able to transmit and receive data. I have enclosed my code. Can anyone help me to solve it? I have used the register for the code.

Communication: USART3

Pins: PB10-TX

STM32 reference manual

[image]
[image]

Here is my code for UART3 single-wire half-duplex communication

```
#include<stm32f10x.h>

char receive;
void USART3_init(void)
{
    RCC->APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_USART3EN ;
    USART3->BRR = 0x0EA6;  //0x1D4C //0x0EA6
    USART3->CR3 |= USART_CR3_HDSEL;
    USART3->CR1 |= USART_CR1_RE ;
    USART3->CR1 |= USART_CR1_TE ;
    USART3->CR1 |= USART_CR1_TCIE;
    
    USART3->CR1 |= USART_CR1_UE;
    
}
int main()
{
    RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_IOPBEN | RCC_APB2ENR_AFIOEN;
    GPIOB->CRH = 0x00000F00;
    
    USART3_init();
    
    while(1)
    {
       USART3->DR = data;
       while (!(USART3->SR & (1<<6)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code has no transmitting and no receiving statements. Please [edit] your question and add it. -- A `while` loop inside an ISR is most of the time plain wrong.

Comment: @thebusybee thanks for the response while loop is to Wait for TC to SET. This indicates that the data has been transmitted

Comment: `GPIOB->CRH = 0x00000F00;` - port is set in open-drain mode. Do you have externall pull-up resistor?

Comment: @Flexz Thank you.  "GPIOB->CRH = 0x00000F00; - port is set in open-drain mode" is done internal in STM32

Comment: Yeah, I know that you want to wait for the completion. However, this is not how interrupt-driven transmission is supposed to be used. Anyway, you change the code. -- How do you know that there is no transmission? Did you measure the line with an oscilloscope? -- There is still no receiving source. How do you know that there is no reception? -- You did not add a statement concerning the necessary pull-up resistor.

Comment: @thebusybee "How do you know that there is no transmission?" I check with the logic analyzer . "There is still no receiving source"-I tried to receive in another controller but i data is not received. " You did not add a statement concerning the necessary pull-up resistor" in STM32 controller pull-up is done internally by configuring the TX pin to Alternate function open-drain.

Comment: Please add such important information to your question by [edit]ing. -- To be clear: Your logic analyzer does not show any transmission. Is this correct? What level does it show? -- "Open drain" is not a synonym for "pull-up". Actually, an open-drain output has no pull-up according to the reference manual. You need to provide an extra pull-up. Please add a resistor and repeat, post the result _in the question_ as advised above.

Comment: figure out which part is not working. EG  use an oscilloscope to check for data on the TX line.

Comment: @thebusybee Thank you.

Comment: @Surendran You don't need open-drain unless there's real concurrency on the line to transmit, i.e. multiple parties try to transmit asynchronously. If by your protocol definition, it's a simple question-answer communication, you can easily use internal pull-up with push-pull output.

Answer (score 3):

I was having a similar issue getting a USART single-wire half-duplex to work on a STM32 microcontroller using ST's Cube MX IDE.

I believe their IDE has a bug in it's code-generation for half-duplex support.  I'm running version v1.2.0 from early 2020, so perhaps its fixed in newer versions, but this is how I got it to work.

What I'm sharing is the difference between going from (a working) full-duplex two-wire UART/USART to a 1-wire half-duplex.  In this particular case, I got it working in "tx-only" instead of rx/tx.  I'll share that difference below.

So this is how I'm configuring the pin in the "Device Configuration Tool":

[image]

And here is the other configuration for the peripheral:

[image]

Next, these are the code *changes* that you'll need to make to `stm32l4xx_hal_msp.c`.  I found that the STM32 Cube MX tool completely removed the calls to `HAL_GPIO_Init()` in its generated code which is wrong.

So again, these are the changes I needed to make between a working full-duplex and my new half-duplex configuration in `stm32l4xx_hal_msp.c`.  I found all the other generated code to be correct:

```
    @@ -557,7 +492,6 @@ void HAL_UART_MspInit(UART_HandleTypeDef* huart)
     __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
     /**USART2 GPIO Configuration
     PA2     ------> USART2_TX
-    PA15 (JTDI)     ------> USART2_RX
     */
     GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = VCP_TX_Pin;
     GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
@@ -566,13 +500,6 @@ void HAL_UART_MspInit(UART_HandleTypeDef* huart)
     GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF7_USART2;
     HAL_GPIO_Init(VCP_TX_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

-    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = VCP_RX_Pin;
-    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
-    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
-    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
-    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF3_USART2;
-    HAL_GPIO_Init(VCP_RX_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);
-
   /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_MspInit 1 */

   /* USER CODE END USART2_MspInit 1 */
@@ -600,7 +527,7 @@ void HAL_UART_MspDeInit(UART_HandleTypeDef* huart)
     PA2     ------> USART2_TX
     PA15 (JTDI)     ------> USART2_RX
     */
-    HAL_GPIO_DeInit(GPIOA, VCP_TX_Pin|VCP_RX_Pin);
+    HAL_GPIO_DeInit(GPIOA, VCP_TX_Pin);^M

   /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_MspDeInit 1 */
```

And here is a graphical screenshot from `gitk` in case you prefer its presentation:

[image]